# In IE7 Jquery Selector not working

Tags: jquery

I have a simple html like -

```
<div id="mainDiv">
 <form method="post">
   <input type="hidden" id="txtId" value="123">
 </form>
</div>
```

I am using following selector for accessing hidden field -

```
var txtVal = $('#mainDiv #txtID').val();
alert(txtVal);
```

which is working fine in FF and cheome but in IE7, alert is saying "undefined".

Comment: It's because the element's id is `txtId` and you're looking for `txtID` (note d/D).

Comment: I am so sorry. By mistake I have written "txtID". actually it is "txtId". Thanks

Comment: @Saurabhn, does your code lie inside a `ready` handler?

Comment: Yes, I would do so. Even an id selector is not guaranteed to match anything before the DOM becomes ready.

Comment: Done, but still getting undefined :(.  Also, when I use alert($('#mainDiv #txtId')), it gives me [Object object] but when I try to fetch value by saying, alert($('#mainDiv #txtId').val()), then it gives "undefined".

Comment: This get solved. For input field I have define a class, class="txtClass" and accessing as, $('#mainDiv .txtClass').val();

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the ID of the element is `txtId` and you're using `txtID` (upper case D) in the selector.

Also, why are you using two selectors when just `#txtId` would be fine?

Comment: There *is* a difference between `#mainDiv #txtID` and `#txtID`. The former doesn't match `#txtID` if it isn't a descendant of `#mainDiv`. (I think I'd avoid designing things that way, but still...)

Answer (score 0):

Selectors are case sensitive:

```
var txtVal = $('#mainDiv #txtID').val();
```

should be:

```
var txtVal = $('#mainDiv #txtId').val();
```

since the input `id="txtId"`. Notice the lowercase `d`.

Answer (score 0):

IE must be more strict about case. Change `#txtID` to `#txtId` (lowercase 'd')

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
    var txtVal = $('#mainDiv #txtId').val();
```

By the way, ID is unique, why not using only #txtId ?

```
    var txtVal = $('#txtId').val();
```